# Determine when a web service is available

Tags: c#, web-services, delphi

How i can determine when a web service is available (on-line)? in Delphi or C#?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just do a valid call to the web service.  If it times out, or you get a 404 error, the web service is not available.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this method..

```
    public bool IsAddressAvailable(string address)
    {
        try
        {
            using(System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadData(address);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

...and call it like this...

```
MessageBox.Show(IsAddressAvailable("http://localhost/my.webservices/mywebservice.asmx").ToString());
```

Comment: I like this (and have used it, thanks!) but would suggest you add a USING statement when you instantiate the client object.
Especially since this is a ping which will be used a lot, it's important that it is disposed.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use it. If it works, then it's available. If it doesn't, then it isn't (or you have network-connection problems between you and the server). There's no magic here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I Wrote this code in Delphi .Net

```
function WebService_OnLine(UrlWebService:String): Boolean;
Var
urlCheck  : uri;
request   : WebRequest;
response  : WebResponse;
begin
MemoLogWebService.Lines.Add('Testing WebService');
urlCheck    := Uri.Create(UrlWebService);
request     := WebRequest.CreateDefault(urlCheck);
request.Timeout := 20000;
    try
         response :=request.GetResponse();
         MemoLogWebService.Lines.Add(response.Headers.ToString);
         Result:=True;
    except
      on E : Exception do
      Begin
         MemoLogWebService.Lines.Add(E.Message);
         Result:=False;
      End;
    end;
End;
```

P.S  : Thank you very much for giving me the inspiration.

Comment: You should narrow your exception trap to communication based exceptions.  You rarely if ever want to trap Exception since that could be a catastrophic error in addition to communication based exceptions.